# Can't install latest python package on Openshift python 3.3 cartridge using requirements.txt file

Tags: python, pip, openshift

I'm getting this message when I push my source code to openshift python cartridge.

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement requests==2.9.1
```

It seems like pip can't find the package version specified in the `requirements.txt` file, yet it's the latest version and it's available in pypi package index directory. How can I force pip to use pypi index instead of the index it's using right now?

how to reproduce this error:

```
rhc app-create py33 python-3.3
cd py33
touch requirements.txt
echo requests==2.9.1 >> requirements.txt
git add .
git commit -a -m "requests2.9.1"
git push
```

openshift server response is:

```
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 274 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Stopping Python 3.3 cartridge
remote: Waiting for stop to finish
remote: Waiting for stop to finish
remote: Building git ref 'master', commit b6b983c
remote: Activating virtenv
remote: Checking for pip dependency listed in requirements.txt file..
remote: The directory '/var/lib/openshift/56b712f40c1e668ab20001a3/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
remote: The directory '/var/lib/openshift/56b712f40c1e668ab20001a3/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
remote: Collecting requests==2.9.1 (from -r /var/lib/openshift/56b712f40c1e668ab20001a3/app-root/runtime/repo/requirements.txt (line 1))
remote:   Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement requests==2.9.1 (from -r /var/lib/openshift/56b712f40c1e668ab20001a3/app-root/runtime/repo/requirements.txt (line 1)) (from versions: 0.2.0, 0.2.1, 0.2.2, 0.2.3, 0.2.4, 0.3.0, 0.3.1, 0.3.2, 0.3.3, 0.3.4, 0.4.0, 0.4.1, 0.5.0, 0.5.1, 0.6.0, 0.6.1, 0.6.2, 0.6.3, 0.6.4, 0.6.5, 0.6.6, 0.7.0, 0.7.1, 0.7.2, 0.7.3, 0.7.4, 0.7.5, 0.7.6, 0.8.0, 0.8.1, 0.8.2, 0.8.3, 0.8.4, 0.8.5, 0.8.6, 0.8.7, 0.8.8, 0.8.9, 0.9.0, 0.9.1, 0.9.2, 0.9.3, 0.10.0, 0.10.1, 0.10.2, 0.10.3, 0.10.4, 0.10.6, 0.10.7, 0.10.8, 0.11.1, 0.11.2, 0.12.0, 0.12.1, 0.13.0, 0.13.1, 0.13.2, 0.13.3, 0.13.4, 0.13.5, 0.13.6, 0.13.7, 0.13.8, 0.13.9, 0.14.0, 0.14.1, 0.14.2, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.0.4, 1.1.0, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.2.3, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.1.0, 2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.3.0, 2.4.0, 2.4.1, 2.4.2, 2.4.3, 2.5.0, 2.5.1, 2.5.2, 2.5.3, 2.6.0, 2.6.1, 2.6.2, 2.7.0, 2.8.0, 2.8.1)
remote: No matching distribution found for requests==2.9.1 (from -r /var/lib/openshift/56b712f40c1e668ab20001a3/app-root/runtime/repo/requirements.txt (line 1))
remote: Running setup.py script..
remote: running develop
remote: running egg_info
remote: creating YourAppName.egg-info
remote: writing YourAppName.egg-info/PKG-INFO
remote: writing dependency_links to YourAppName.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
remote: writing top-level names to YourAppName.egg-info/top_level.txt
remote: writing manifest file 'YourAppName.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
remote: reading manifest file 'YourAppName.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
remote: writing manifest file 'YourAppName.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
remote: running build_ext
remote: Creating /var/lib/openshift/56b712f40c1e668ab20001a3/app-root/runtime/dependencies/python/virtenv/venv/lib/python3.3/site-packages/YourAppName.egg-link (link to .)
remote: Adding YourAppName 1.0 to easy-install.pth file
remote:
remote: Installed /var/lib/openshift/56b712f40c1e668ab20001a3/app-root/runtime/repo
remote: Processing dependencies for YourAppName==1.0
remote: Finished processing dependencies for YourAppName==1.0
remote: Preparing build for deployment
remote: Deployment id is 19c7fb7b
remote: Activating deployment
remote: Starting Python 3.3 cartridge (Apache+mod_wsgi)
remote: Application directory "/" selected as DocumentRoot
remote: Application "wsgi.py" selected as default WSGI entry point
remote: -------------------------
remote: Git Post-Receive Result: success
remote: Activation status: success
remote: Deployment completed with status: success
To ssh://56b712f40c1e668ab20001a3@py33-chaticha.rhcloud.com/~/git/py33.git/
   be50ea8..b6b983c  master -> master
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** after [submitting this problem to openshift bug reporting system](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1307233#c0) they resolved the issue and now everything is working as expected.

The reason for the problem, as "Vu Dinh" there said, was:

> We do maintain a mirror for PyPi for our OpenShift system. So, sometimes, when a new package comes out in PyPi, our mirror will need to be resynced and during that time, the issue that you mentioned may occur.

And they had to resync the mirror to resolve this issue:

> the mirror has been resynced and I have tested it on my end. The issue has been resolved and you should be able to install the newest version requests. Please give it a try and let us know the result.

---

Original Answer:

I couldn't find any solution for the problem I described, so for now I'm using two lines of commands in `deploy` action hook as a temporary fix for my problem:

```
echo "installing dependencies..."
pip install -r "$OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR"requirements.txt
```